# CSS changes are not applied immediately

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

to lower the head should change color, but the change is not seen, if I open the menu only then change can be seen.

```
<ion-header-bar class="thediv" ng-class="{scrolling: isActive}">
     <ion-nav-bar class="bar-clear "  >         
     </ion-nav-bar>
     </ion-header-bar>
```

my class:

```
.scrolling{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

and code:

```
if ($ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('contentScroll').getScrollPosition().top > 100) {       
     $scope.isActive = true;
} else {
    $scope.isActive = false;
}
```

## Demo

http://virtual-host-discourse.global.ssl.fastly.net/uploads/ionicframework/optimized/2X/7/7fcbaa68a40008e90de10292d80559c3eb5e17bf_1_326x500.gif

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you please share a fiddle?

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea, not sure how to fix it, if I were you I would try to figure out how the $watch, $digest, and $apply are handling it. If it is not updating right when you start to scroll that may be an issue. You could also try to maybe do a $broadcast event when scrolling starts and then apply the class based on that the event. Just some ideas, let me know if you get it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my assumption is that the digest loop is not processed  when you affect `$scope.isActive`.

Try to wrap it into a `$timeout` (don't forget to add `$timeout` as a dependency)

```
if ($ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('contentScroll').getScrollPosition().top > 100) {       
  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.isActive = true;
  },0)
} else {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.isActive = false;
  },0)
}
```